# Save state to SQLite table via custom adapter for items that have been bookmarked

Tags: java, android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have progressed with my app but I am stuck with trying to figure out what needs to be implemented to retrieve a button's (an imageview in this example) state in my custom adapter from a sqlite table which will maintain entries for all rows (by _id) that have been bookmarked.

Below if my custom SimpleCursorAdapter that I have been able to get the imageview to change using setSelected() so now I need to create the mechanism to identify items that have been bookmarked and store it in a table. I have put //comments on what I envision in doing but not sure how to implement it...

```
public class DxSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
Context context;
Activity activity;
    private DxDbAdapter mDbHelper;

public DxSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context=context;
    this.activity=(Activity) context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.fav);

    //Query for _id of row item and see if there is an entry for it on the favourite table
    //Then change ImageView to being selected image (yellow star)
    //Else leave default image (greyed out)


    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView fav = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav);

            long rowID = (Long) v.getTag();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "" + rowID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            mDbHelper = new DxDbAdapter(context);
            int result = mDbHelper.isFav(rowID);

            if (result == 0) {
                v.setSelected(true);
            }
            else {
                v.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });
    return row;
}
}
```

Also, I have an adapter for my database which I am creating functions to be able to add a favourite entry into the table but I don't know how I can call upon the db when in the custom cursor adapter or if I need to go about it in a different way.

```
public class DxDbAdapter {

public static final String DIAG_ID = "_id";
public static final String DIAG_CAT = "category";
public static final String DIAG_SUB = "subcategory";
public static final String DIAG = "diagnosis";
public static final String DIAG_CODE = "diagcode";
public static final String FAV_CODE = "edid";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dx";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

protected static Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String s;
            try {
                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "1", 2000).show();
                    InputStream in = mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
                    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
                    NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
                    for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                            s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                            db.execSQL(s);
                    }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, t.toString(), 50000).show();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DiagLookups");
            onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DxDbAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mCtx = context;
}

public DxDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDb.close();
}

public Cursor fetch(int level, String param) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    switch (level) {
    case 0:
        cursor = mDb.rawQuery("Select distinct _id, diagnosis, diagcode, favourite From DiagLookup Where category = ? order by diagnosis asc", new String[]{""+param});
        break;
    case 1:
        cursor = mDb.rawQuery("Select distinct _id, diagnosis, diagcode, favourite From DiagLookup Where subcategory = ? order by diagnosis asc", new String[]{""+param});
        break;
    }
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor fetchFavs() {
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("Select distinct _id, diagnosis, diagcode, favourite From DiagLookup Where favourite = 1 order by diagnosis asc", null);
    return cursor;
}

public int isFav(Long param) {      
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("Select favourite From DiagLookup Where _id = ?", new String[]{""+param});
    int result = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FAV));
    return result;
}
```

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lookup (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
category VARCHAR(150),
subcategory VARCHAR(150),
diagnosis VARCHAR(150),
diagcode VARCHAR(150),
favourite INTEGER)
```

I have a listactivity which I create the db and open() it. From there I fetch() the data into a cursor and pass it onto my DxSimpleCursorAdapter.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the [`bindView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#bindView%28android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor%29) and the [`newView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ResourceCursorAdapter.html#newView%28android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) methods so you'll have access to the cursor. In `newView()` you inflate the layout:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // you should put this in the constructor so you don't do it every time the newView() method is called
      View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
      // even implement the view holder pattern for a small performance boost
      ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_image); 
      row.setTag(holder);
      return row;
}
```

`ViewHolder` is a class in your adapter that will hold the views so we don't search the entire layout every time we want to access the rows views:

```
class ViewHolder {
     ImageView image;
     // other views that you have in your row layout
}
```

Then implement the `bindView()` method:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context con, Cursor cursor) {
      ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag() //retrieve the holder with the row views
      // set the current image status
      int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(FAV_CODE)); // get the status( I don't know how you store the favorite status, I assumed is an int in the FAV_CODE column, 1 for favorite, 0 for unpicked yet)
      if (status == 1) {
          // the user set as favorite
          holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite); // set the favorite drawable
      } else {
         // this isn't a favorite so put the default image
         holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal); // set the normal drawable 
      } 
      //get the row id from the cursor that we will pass in the onClick method as a tag for the image
      long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DIAG_ID));
      holder.image.setTag(new Long(id)); 
      // set the image listener
      holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
             long rowID = (Long) v.getTag();
             //there is no need to find the view, and you don't modify the imageview image from here    
             // query the database to find the row with the _id equal to rowID
             // find out what value we have in the column with the image status (either 1 or 0 meaning favorite or not favorite)
             // update the row with the new status (if you have 1 in the database then update the status with 0 , if you have 0 in the database then update the value with 1)
             //call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter to let the adapter know about the update, I don't know if this call will work with SimpleCursorAdapter, you may have to set a new adapter on the ListView with a new cursor.
         }
      });

}
```

Comment: Under newView() the code holder.image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_image); does not work since it says findViewByID is undefined for DxSimpleCursorAdapter even though I have imported android.view.View. I tried to use the following   row.setTag(holder.image.findViewById(R.id.fav)); which didn't create any errors but I ended up getting a forced closed error when emulating the app and it was due to a NullPointerException.

Comment: @DeucePie Sorry about that. You must search for that id in the inflated row layout. See my small edit.

Comment: what is the difference between using getView(), as was my approach, with bindView()?

Comment: @DeucePie None in your situation, in the case of cursor based adapters the `getView` method delegates the list row creation to the 2 method `newView` and `bindView`. With those methods you have more control on how your adapter builds its data. For example with `getView` you rely on the adapter binding the cursor data to the current row, if you want to customize this will have to implement the `bindView` method.

Comment: I have implemented your solution and it is working but I am stuck now at the point where I actually update the value on my table depending if the user has clicked on a marked item or not. `public void onClick(View v) {
ImageView fav = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fav);
fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav);
long rowID = (Long) v.getTag();
If () { v.setSelected(true); \\Update favourite value on sql table with 1}
Else { v.setSelected(false); \\Update favourite value on sql table with 0`

Comment: @DeucePie I don't know your database implementation so I've updated my answer with some words on what actions to follow to update the data.

Comment: I have updated my code above to show the current state of my onClick() and also my DxDbAdapter class which shows how the database implementation is. At the moment my call to isFav() is bringing back a NullPointerException which I am not sure what is causing that. Any more guidance on how I can properly access the db and call the methods?

Comment: @DeucePie You have some errors in the `onClick` method and database declaration. I've made a simple example that you can check here http://pastebin.com/6BWqacCt . See the database declaration and selects.

Comment: thanks for the code. it was very useful and the only problem i have is around the notifydatasetchanged() by making a new adapter. When I fetch the data I have a value I pass into it by using subcategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("SUBCATEGORY"); when I place it within the OnClick() it says getIntent() is undefined. SO there must be another way to pass this value onto the new adapter. Any ideas?

Comment: @DeucePie The `getIntent()` method is an `Activity` related method so you somehow have to get a reference to your `Activity` that is using the adapter. Look at your adapter constructor, you should require a `Context`(in generally an `Activity` reference is passed there) so you should already have the required reference.